# Trying to run and access HSQLDB standalone without luck

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am trying to run and access HSQLDB standalone without luck..

I started the database and I got the following output:

```
@wcmisdlin07 ~/Downloads/hsqldb-2.2.9/hsqldb/bin> ./runServer.bat 
: No such file or directory: ..data
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@7e896e10]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@7e896e10]: Could not load properties from file
[Server@7e896e10]: Using cli/default properties only
[Server@7e896e10]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@7e896e10]: Server socket opened successfully in 7 ms.
[Server@7e896e10]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:test, alias=] opened sucessfully in 690 ms.
[Server@7e896e10]: Startup sequence completed in 698 ms.
[Server@7e896e10]: 2013-04-30 13:59:44.616 HSQLDB server 2.2.9 is online on port 9001
[Server@7e896e10]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@7e896e10]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

and I am trying to access it in java using the following URL:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb
```

But if you look at the console I am getting the following errors:

```
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @343d0d2b,5,HSQLDB Connections @7e896e10]]: database alias=mydb does not exist
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @7d52cb9a,5,HSQLDB Connections @7e896e10]]: database alias=test does not exist
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @5c1fbd9,5,HSQLDB Connections @7e896e10]]: database alias=xdb does not exist
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @231d06f0,5,HSQLDB Connections @7e896e10]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
[Server@7e896e10]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @545c498e,5,HSQLDB Connections @7e896e10]]: database alias=xdb does not exist
```

So can someone please tell me the default database name or how do I create one?

Answer (score 3):

The [How-To](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html) says you have to create a server.properties file and put it in the directory that you installed hsqldb into, where the file contains:

```
server.database.0=file.hsqldb/dirWhereDbLives   
server.dbname.0=xdb
```

Comment: Correct answer. With your present setup, the connection URL is `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/`